# How to implement an add if not available in the database in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

How do I implement, or what steps do I use to create a transformation that compares a table and a list . For example a database table name Schools and an excel file with a huge list of names of Schools.

if the entry in the excel is not seen in the database, it should then be added to the database table.

I'm not quite sure if I can use the database lookup step, it does not tell if a lookup fails. insert update step doesn't seem a solution as well, for it requires some ID value but no ID is present on the list of schools in the excel file

Comment: can you please post an example of your dataset (both from database and excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what worked for me,

```
excel file --> 
select values (to delete unnecessary fields) -->
database lookup (this will create a new field, and will set null if not found)     -->
filter rows (get the fields with null output from lookup) -->
table output (insert the filtered records)
```

Comment: Lookup is also an option but it will check the complete table every-time (Which is not a good option if you have a continuous growing table). In ETL it is always better to filter out unnecessary records before the logic for improved performance.

Comment: didn't know that, thanks for the info. in my case, it is acceptable to use lookup since the dataset is less than 5k.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information that you provided a simple join with table insert step will do your task. You can use the `Merge rows` step for comparing both the data stream (excel and database). The merge rows step uses the key to compare two streams and add a flag field which marks the row as `new, identical, changed, deleted`. In your case you would like to insert all the rows that are marked as new by using table insert step.

Please check the below links for more reference.

[Merge rows](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Merge+rows), [Synchronize after merge](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Synchronize+after+merge)

Comment: Cool, please let me know if you face any issue. I had done it couple of times.